# Why does it not execute the method with reflection

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, methods

I am trying to execute a method in a class from within it with reflection. Althoough the method exists, I am still getting the MethodNotFound Exception

```
public virtual void ExecuteMethod(string MethodName) 
    {
        if(this is ISelectable)
        {
            Type thisType = (this as ISelectable).GetType();
            thisType.InvokeMember(MethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public , null, null, null);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Add( ) { }
```

Maybe it it worth to say that this methods are situated in a base class and the ExecuteMethod is beingcalled on the child Class. I don't think it should matter, but anyway.

Comment: Is this method you are trying to invoke static?

Comment: Then you need an instance to pass on the invoke method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the *method* to execute, but not which *object* to execute it on. You cannot just execte something on a *type*, you need to specify a concrete object. You use the type to get the metadata of the method, then that information is used to invoke the method on an actual object. [Check this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details.

That second to last `null` should be the object, probably `this` in your case.

Comment: This was the last thing missing

Comment: @user853710 - just out of curiosity, why did you unmark my answer? I did mention that you were missing the `this` from the parameter list, it's highlighted in my answer. Still, it's over to you whose answer you accept...

Comment: sorry buddy. must have been a double click or accident

Comment: @user853710 No problems, like I said it's always up to the question asker to select which (if any) answer is marked... I was just curious. All good :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx):

> You must specify `Instance` or `Static` along with `Public` or `NonPublic` or
>   no members will be returned.

From the code it seems that in your case the method is `static`, so add `BindingFlags.Static`.

Comment: Not to mention it's also good to combine in `FlattenHeirarchy`. Although that's not his only problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a instance of the object that has the method

```
thisType.InvokeMember(MethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, null
    , this // instance of the object which has the method
    , null);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another way

```
MethodInfo _methodinfo= type.GetMethod(MethodName);
_methodinfo.Invoke(null, null)
```

Comment: You are assuming the method is being invoked on a static class - you should mention this, otherwise your code is going to fail.

Comment: no buddy this code is tested you make a Test class C                    and in type you mention Type type = typeof(C) which contains the method. before giving a negative comment you should get your facts checked

Comment: Let me point you to [the doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx), and then also direct you to the TargetException in the Exceptions section. The first argument can only be null when working with a **static** class.

Comment: Ok Ok Ok I got what you are trying to say. I have used some static constructors and all while making the test program thank you for correcting me and sorry :)

Comment: No worries, you just need to point that sort of thing out otherwise the person who asks the question is going to try it and then come back with more questions if it doesn't work for them. All good :)